# Why is the 'else' statement not executing in my loop even though the criteria for the 'if' statement is not met?

Tags: python, loops

I am solving the following problem on Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/submissions/

Where basically we have a list of parentheses s, and are checking if it is 'valid'.

Example:

```
Input: s = "()[]{}"
Output: true

Input: s = "(]"
Output: false
```

Basically the parentheses need to be closed in the right order.

Here is my code:

```
def isValid(s: str) -> bool:
    stack = []
    open_brackets = ["(", "[", "{"]

    for bracket in s:
        if bracket in open_brackets:
            stack.append(bracket)

        else:
            if bracket == "]":
                if stack.pop() != "[":
                    return False

            elif bracket == ")":
                if stack.pop() != "(":
                    return False

            elif bracket == "}":
                if stack.pop != "{":
                    return False
        return True
```

For some reason, it is failing the test for input: `s="(]"` ; this is clearly supposed to return False, but it is returning True.

I printed the stack at the end of my code, and I am getting `["("]`, which means the `else statement` is not executing for some reason. Any ideas why- I have looked over this so many times and can't figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Your `return True` is inside loop. So the loop will iterate only once

Comment: Un-indent the `return True` statement - right now it exits the function with first run of `for`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return True` statement prevents the other code from running, meaning it exits on the first loop.

Unindent it and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Unindent the final `return True` such that the loop can iterate through all characters in the input string:

```py
def isValid(s: str) -> bool:
    stack = []
    open_brackets = ["(", "[", "{"]

    for bracket in s:
        if bracket in open_brackets:
            stack.append(bracket)

        else:
            if bracket == "]":
                if stack.pop() != "[":
                    return False

            elif bracket == ")":
                if stack.pop() != "(":
                    return False

            elif bracket == "}":
                if stack.pop != "{":
                    return False
    return True
```